# How to set the maximum size of a slider in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, slider, wpf-controls

I have a UserControl containing a slider (for a thermometer). I want to fix the slider's max height/width, so when I reuse it in another project, even if I resize the window, the slider stays the same size.

Comment: Every FrameworkElement has a MaxWidth and MaxHeight property.

Comment: Solved the problem. Thank you!